# Java Applet Animation Not Working (Teleporting)

Tags: java, animation, applet, awt, event-dispatch-thread

I'm trying to create a simple animation where my program will animate the specified shape from left to right upon pressing a button. However, when I run my program and press the animate button, the shape starts on the left of the screen but teleports to the middle of screen without transition/animation. If someone could help me explain why my paint () method doesn't animate and how to fix it, it would be greatly appreciated.

Paint method:

```
public void paint (Graphics g)
{
    g.drawString ("Set Size (1-400)", 640, 80);

    if (animate == true)
    {
        if (time > 0)
        {
            switch (colourNum)
            {
                case 1:
                    g.setColor (Color.red);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    g.setColor (Color.green);
                    break;

                case 3:
                    g.setColor (Color.blue);
                    break;

                case 4:
                    g.setColor (Color.yellow);
                    break;
            }

            switch (shapeNum)
            {
                case 1:
                    g.fillRect (x, y, size, size);
                    g.setFont (textFont);
                    g.drawString ("Shape: Square", x, 800);
                    g.drawString ("Size: " + size, x, 840);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    g.fillRoundRect (x, y, size, size, 30, 30);
                    g.setFont (textFont);
                    g.drawString ("Shape: Round Square", x, 800);
                    g.drawString ("Size: " + size, x, 840);
                    break;

                case 3:
                    g.fillOval (x, y, size, size);
                    g.setFont (textFont);
                    g.drawString ("Shape: Circle", x, 800);
                    g.drawString ("Size: " + size, x, 840);
                    break;

                case 4:
                    g.fillArc (x, y, size, size, 360, 180);
                    g.setFont (textFont);
                    g.drawString ("Shape: Semi Circle", x, 800);
                    g.drawString ("Size: " + size, x, 840);
                    break;
            }

            x = x + 5;
            time = time - 1;

            try
            {
                Thread.sleep (100);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex)
            {
            }

            repaint ();
        }
        animate = false;
    }
```

Action Performed Method code:

```
else if (evt.getSource () == bttn2)
    {
        if (draw == false)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Invalid order of user-input has occured\n     DRAW BEFORE ANIMATE", "Exception or Error", 0);

        }
        else
        {
            animate = true;
            time = 500;
            x = 0;
            repaint ();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `public void paint (Graphics g) { ..Thread.sleep (100); .. repaint ();` This is **not** the correct way to approach animation in a Swing or AWT based GUI. In more modern times we'd use a Swing based `Timer` to trigger `repaint()`. General tips: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). ..

Comment: .. 3) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).